# Not able to call a web service hosted in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've published a OWIN hosted web service to my remote cluster.  I'm using a custom port 4444 created during the cluster creation.   I see the AppPort rule for 4444.  I'm also able to remote to one of the VM, and invoke the service locally.   However, I'm still not able to call it remotely.   It hangs for a while and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? Is it possible to try port 80 for HTTP or port 443 for HTTPS?

Comment: Did you specify 4444 in the servicemianifest file as the service endpoint and implemented the CreateServiceInstanceListeners() method? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/

Comment: I'm using HTTP, the cluster was not set to use secured.   4444 is in the manifest file, otherwise it would not work locally on the VM node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this guide and make sure you have the Azure Load Balancer configured properly: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/#service-fabric-in-azure

The trick is to make sure that when the load balancer sends traffic on a particular port to a node in the cluster there is a service instance there listening on that port. By default, the load balancer simply sends traffic to all nodes, so you have to make sure that you have a service instance listening on each node, or if not then have a load balancer probe actively checking which nodes do have a service instance listening on that port.

Comment: I got it working.  I have a probe rule that's HTTP, setting it back to TCP works.